# Explode a cell populated with multiple values into unique rows

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, explode

I want to "explode" each cell that has multiple words in it into distinct rows while retaining it's rating and sysnet value when being conjoined. I attempted to import someone's pandas_explode library but VS code just does not want to recognize it. Is there any way for me in pandas documentation or some nifty for loop that'll extract and redistribute these words? Example csv is in the img link

```
import json
import pandas as pd # version 1.01

df = pd.read_json('result.json')
df.to_csv('jsonToCSV.csv', index=False) 
df = pd.read_csv('jsonToCSV.csv') 


df = df.explode('words')

print(df)

df = df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\alant\Desktop\test.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Output when running above:

```
   synset  rating                                              words
0     1034312     0.0             ['discourse', 'talk about', 'discuss']
1      146856     0.0          ['merging', 'meeting', 'coming together']
2      829378     0.0     ['care', 'charge', 'tutelage', 'guardianship']
3     8164585     0.0  ['administration', 'governance', 'governing bo...
4     1204318     0.0               ['nonhierarchical', 'nonhierarchic']
...       ...     ...                                                ...
8605  7324673     1.0               ['emergence', 'outgrowth', 'growth']
```

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d53To.png)

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? The latest has a built-in `explode()` function

Comment: I am using version 1.01 on python 3.7.3 on my wsl on vs code

Comment: Have you made an attempt using the [df.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) function?

Comment: synset  rating                                              words
0     1034312     0.0             ['discourse', 'talk about', 'discuss']
1      146856     0.0          ['merging', 'meeting', 'coming together']
2      829378     0.0     ['care', 'charge', 'tutelage', 'guardianship']
... This is what i get when running df.explode('words') so I am assuming exploding the column did not work. Do i have to indicate a cell somehow?

Comment: Please include your sample input and output as text in your question rather than images or comments, to make a [mcve]

Comment: I've re-edited the post to hopefully provide more clarity @G.Anderson

Comment: check if list is not string

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. When I copy your dataframe and run either `df.explode('words')` or `df.explode(column='words')` I get each list element in a row. For example (after calling `to_dict()`): `{'synset': 1034312, 'rating': 0.0, 'words': 'discourse'}, {'synset': 1034312, 'rating': 0.0, 'words': 'talk about'}, {'synset': 1034312, 'rating': 0.0, 'words': 'discuss'}...`

Comment: @G.Anderson Is there a way for me to check if the entire words column is a long string or a list?

Comment: I would use something like `[i for i in df['words'] if not isinstance(i,list)]` to see which elements are not lists

Comment: I ran this (for i in df['words'] :  if(not isinstance(i,list)):print('x') ), and it outputted a lot of x's. So along the way my column got changed into strings. Is there a way for me to transform the strings back into lists?

Answer (score 0):

If you have columns that needs to be kept from exploding, I suggest setting them as index first and then explode.

For your example, try if this works for you.

```
df = df.set_index(['synset','rating']).apply(pd.Series.explode) # this would work for exploding multiple columns as well

# then reset the index

df = df.reset_index()
```